# How to convert Ordered Dict to instance of django model

Tags: django-rest-framework

There are models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')

class Street(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    street = models.ForeignKey(Street, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    house = models.SmallIntegerField()
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
```

and there are serializers:

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class StreetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model =  Street
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'city']

#  Not working but it's not important, becase i can replace id of city by name in StringRelatedField
    def create(self, validated_data):
        city_data = validated_data.pop('city')
        city = City.objects.create(**city_data)
        street = Street.objects.create(**validated_data)


class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer()
    street = StreetSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'city', 'street', 'house', 'opening_time', 'closing_time']


# This is important, it have to work
    def create(self, validated_data):
        city_data = validated_data.pop('city')
        city = City.objects.create(name=city_data['name'])
        street_data = validated_data.pop('street')
        street = Street.objects.create(name = street_data['name'], city = city)
        shop = Shop.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # This occures NoneType
        shop.city.add(city)
        # This not working at all
        shop.street = street
        return shop
```

But I have error **ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('name', 'Ryazan')])": "Street.city" must be a "City" instance.**
How to convert ordered dict to model instance? If i Tried use **init**, i don't have ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You are not unpacking the nested city and street data correctly. You need to use .get(...) [drf-doc] to extract a model instance:
    city = City.objects.get_or_create(name=city_data['name'])
    street = Street.objects.get_or_create(name=street_data['name'], city=city)
    shop = Shop.objects.create(
        name=validated_data['name'],
        city=city,
        street=street,
        house=validated_data['house'],
        opening_time=validated_data['opening_time'],
        closing_time=validated_data['closing_time'])
You here thus obtain City and Street instances, and use those to construct the Shop instance.
Note: You should make use of .get_or_create(...) [django-doc] here to prevent creating duplicate City and Street objects in case they already exist.
Furthermore it is normally better to make use ofSlugRelatedFields [drf-doc] to refer to related objects, since then hyperlinked representations are possible, and the client does not have to submit IDs, but can submit more "user friendly" values like slugs.

Note: It is normally better to make use of Django's CASCADE ON DELETE semantics, than to set NULL in a ForeignKey. By setting NULL, you end up with Shop objects that refer to no City or Street, which often does not make a lot of sense. By using CASCADE, the related Shop objects are deleted when you delete a City or Street, which often models the real world more accurately.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working very well. I tried to use SlugRelatedField, but all ruined again. I can't user read only, that's why i use parametr ```queryset = City/Street.objects.all()```. But then  i raised exception that i use in views. Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: StringField doesn't work as well(